# Porting a C library to C++

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I would like to know if this is the correct way to port a `C` library to `C++`; for this example I wrote a 2 line C header with a function and a `typedef` managing a pointer.

*lib.h*

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

#include <math.h>

double foo(double a) { return (log(a)); }

typedef double (*PtoFoo)(double);

#endif // LIB_H
```

*lib.hpp*

```
#ifndef LIB_HPP
#define LIB_HPP

namespace lib {
extern "C" {
#include "lib.h"
}
}

#endif // LIB_HPP
```

and a little test in `C++11`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lib.hpp"
#include <functional>

int main() {
  // call to the function
  std::cout << lib::foo(42354.343) << "\n";
  // trying the pointer to function type
  lib::PtoFoo ptr = lib::foo;
  std::function<double(double)> f(ptr);
  std::cout << f(342.4) << "\n";
  return (0);
}
```

right now my attention is focused on pointers, function pointers and functions, but in general I would like to know if this is the correct way to port standard `C` code to `C++` and using the new c++ interface with namespaces without possible backfires .

Comment: C++ is deliberately designed to be C compatible, so outside of `extern "C" {` (which could even be put before the `#include` of your headers, if you wanted to...) there is much porting to do. Of course, you may want to rewrite (or wrap) things to be C++ friendly, then it is a different story....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the original C library it's not a project that I can edit or manipulate, it's a C library that I can use but I need to use it in C++, so I need to wrap C++ around C without basically interfering with the given C library or headers; I need you to expand your idea about this because I don't have a specific idea about what you are talking about.

Comment: The C Library is perfectly compatible with C++11. Or you can use `#ifdef __cplusplus`, which will define the C++ interface

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm referring especially to the last part of your comment .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way to do it.

Alternatively, you can use the `__cplusplus` preprocessor token to define the C++ interface in the same header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace lib {
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
}
#endif
```

The advantage of this approach is that only a single header file is required.

Comment: thanks, but I don't think I can use that because the original `C` library it's not a project of mine. I assume that this token is for a `C` compiler that doesn't understand both `namespace` and `extern` directives and for nothing else.

Comment: @user2485710: (Replying here, but it applies to all your comments). So far you have been _assuming_ that there is a problem, and you certainly haven't shown us a real problem. I'd suggest that you close this question, **use the C library**, and only **if** there is a problem using it, ask a question. And then show us the **exact** problem you have, including error messages.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, C++ is designed to be compatible with C, so just wrapping your C library headers with the appropriate `extern "C" {` and `} /* end extern "C"*/;` is enough.

However, you may want to design a C++ friendly interface to your library. This requires some thoughts, and some code (most of it in C++ specific header files). For instance, you may want to provide interfaces using C++ object, overloading, operator, and template facilities.

I can't help more, but look for examples at: [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) and its [C++ bindings](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion/tree/master/src/bindings/cpp), [GTKmm](http://www.gtkmm.org) which is a large C++ binding to [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/documentation.php) (and companion libraries like `Glib`...), the [C++ class interface](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html#C_002b_002b-Class-Interface) to [gmplib](https://gmplib.org), or even the newest [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) standard [thread library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) (i.e. [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) etc, etc...) which could be viewed as a clever C++ wrapping of [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) ....

I believe that each library could have its own C++ wrapping... How to design that is up to you... (depends a lot on the wrapped library, your available time, and your fluency with C++...).